# maintain SEO of a website on platform change?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a site url
http://www.dualfocusphotography.co.uk

i want to convert it to word-press in such a way its SEO or site ranking should not be disturbed.

any one guide me is it possible if yes then how?

any help or relevant-materiel would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you are doing that you expect will disturb your SEO? Don't do those. If you don't know how to avoid doing them, then ask specific questions about them.

Comment: for example there are page name, but in wordpress url will be rewritten which definitely will move your page rank to 0

Comment: Changing the title of a page isn't going to have a significant impact on SEO. Or did you mean the URI? If so, I suggest you ask a question about how to maintain existing URIs when changing to a different CMS. You'd probably be better off asking it on the [Wordpress Stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main SEO issue when you try to move your site into wordpress is with the old indexed URLs by Google. 
You must set "301 moved permanently status" to all of your old main urls. 
You have to set an effective 404 page for error pages (WP had one). 
Check for the main keywords through which people reached your site & retain those keywords. Generate new site map & submit in Google webmaster. 
Migrate as quick as possible.
After migrating use WP SEO plugin & use keyword sparingly. 
Use SEO friendly permalink structure.
Use twitter & facebook plugin's for socializing with virtual world.

Some useful links
https://seogadget.co.uk/surviving-seo-site-migration/
http://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/5-tips-for-effective-seo-site-migration/

Answer (score 2):

To keep your rankings, you should define what pages are the most important(have backlinks and are most visited and make sure you set redirects 301 on them.

There is a redirection plugin for wordpress to check for broken links. Doing redirect for all pages can affect the performance, that's why it is better to redirect the most important ones. This way you'll retain your rankings, however, a certain drop is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep the same URLs, it won't matter if you are using from-scratch HTML pages or Wordpress. If you want to change the content around and will have new URLs, you'll need to do 301 redirects from each old page to each new page.

For example, the old page might have been oldsite.com/services.html, you'll do a 301 redirect to newsite.com/location/services

the 301 redirects are done in the .htaccess file.

I just wrote an article on [how to SEO your wordpress site](http://media317.net/2012/5-easy-steps-to-seo-with-wordpress/) that might help you as well

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

When migrating to a new CMS, try to keep your domain unchanged. If that's not possible, you should set up 301 permanent redirect to the following pages: homepage, most popular pages that get lots of traffic (check your analytics for them), pages with backlinks.

- Also, when you change the URL structure, try to include your keywords
  into the address
- Check your robots.txt file - whether it;s indexing correctly
- Generate the new xml sitemap and submit it via google webmaster
  tools.

Answer (score -2):

WordPress has it's own powerfll plugins for SEO. I suggest you use those.

Comment: Specific examples? Usage? Strategy? Anything??

Comment: i am talking about SEO should be maintained not to start it from scratch.

Comment: If you are moving to WordPress you will get to use a plugin from scratch, I don't think you can maintain it. I use All In One SEO Pack.